# How do I update a dataframe every time an action occurs in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I've been looking and haven't found any good answers on this but I am making intense calculations that are very long and very complex. It's hard to keep up with the code if I'm putting all of the equations within a rendering of a Data Table or histogram etc.

Is there an easy way to do something like this as the user puts in their inputs?

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
    df <- data.frame(c(12984+(input$spend *1000), input$sales)
}
```

Comment: Did you know about `reactive()`?

Comment: Indeed, create a reactive object dependent on the relevant sources. [Here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/#reactivity)  is the overview from the folks at RStudio regarding reactivity. Pretty basic thing to understand if you want to develop useful shiny applications.

Comment: I don't know what to do. I need an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments, you should use a [reactive expression](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson6/) to use a reactive input:

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
  # Creation of the reactive function
  df <- reactive({
    data.frame(c(12984+(input$spend *1000), input$sales)
  })

  # Create reactive function output
  output$data <- renderTable( df() )
}
```

Note that the reactive data is a **function**, hence the call to `df()` to generate output.

Comment: I found the answer yesterday. I was missing the `()` after the `df`. You beat me to answering the question lol so congrats!